# Applying multiple forces on a particle

Tags: physics, linear-algebra

If I have a particle, say in a polar coordinate grid, and I want to apply multiple vectors to it, how can I calculate where it's final position will be given those vectors?

Ex. Imagine there's a force represented as a vector, that moves the particle a radius magnitude of 8 at an angle of 45°. Another vector that acts on it at the same time, at magnitude 3 at 90°. How would I calculate the final position of the particle?

Comment: Presumably you've tried applying [standard kinematics equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics) to the problem, like `f = m•a`, `p(t + ∆t) = p(t) + v•∆t + (a/2)∆t²` — what went wrong, or where specifically did you run into trouble?

Comment: I don't have a background in that nor was I even aware of it. I don't need to accelerate the object; I'm not trying to simulate movement second by second. I just want to resolve the final position of a massless particle with two or more forces of varying magnitudes and angles of direction and come up with a final coordinate of where it should be.

Comment: Force creates an acceleration, and only makes sense in the context of objects that have mass. If you don't have mass, you might be talking about velocities, not forces? Or possibly displacements?

Comment: I think displacement or velocity, is what I'm trying to achieve. Mind you this isn't something that needs to be rendered or animated. I'll have a particle/object at coordinate (0,0) and apply two vectors of different angles. If I just had one vectors I would know the answer already. The resulting coordinate would be whatever coordinate that vector is at. But because I've introduced a second vector of a different direction, I don't know how to apply both at the same time. Same time being key there. Not one after the other.

Comment: Isn't this just [vector addition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html) (which is order independent)? If not, can you edit your question to more explicitly describe your desired outcome or what application this is serving?

Comment: I don't think Vector addition gives me the desired outcome. If I have a vector (10, 2) and a vector (6, 4) then the resulting vector is (16, 6). This is undesirable because I would like there to be a limit as to how far the particle can go. The magnitude of the vector should simply determine how much influence it's angle has in the particle's direction of displacement. So if vector 1 "pushes" it (10, 2) with a magnitude of r=sqrt(24), then vector 2 should have less influence in it's angle because it's r is much smaller. Does that make sense? Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: Maybe I need to set a constant "velocity" or something for the particle, and only allow the vectors to influence it's direction. The magnitude of the vector then determines how much influence? Does any of this sound like a typical physics problem that I could lookup a proven solution for?

Comment: Add the input vectors all together, then scale the resulting vector by (maximum_wanted_change / length_of_that_vector) to get the a final vector forced to always the maximum_wanted_change.  I think that for any more specific and useful answers you need to draw out what you're trying to accomplish and clarify the pre and post conditions that you expect.  This rubber-duck debugging may in itself get you to the answer...

Comment: Seph you should update your question. As it stands you can just add the vectors together, but if you need to limit the size of the result then that is extra information.